# populating a new table based upon existing table MySql

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table purchase_mast

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   "autoid","transaction_id","user_id","package_id","purchase_date","unique_id"    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "52","bq4ren25a8w0","CBS_00002","9789386310xxx","2017-04-25 12:30:18","SUR242241" |
| "66","j4ax039ilc00","CBS_00260","9789386310xxx","2017-06-05 12:04:23","MED767885" |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I create a new table score_mast

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "autoid","user_id","genre_id","package_id","timestamp","timestring","percent_marks","level_cleared","test_id" |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want that from purchase_mast, `user_id + package_id` to be copied into score_mast, row by row.

Is this possible in mysql, without using PHP scripting. if yes then please guide me.

Comment: I don't see an obvious mapping for every column in the new table.

Comment: I just want that all rows from purchase_mast to be copied into score_mast (only user_id+package_id fields). Rest fields will be populated later. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: A typical way to do this is with `INSERT INTO score_mast ... SELECT ... FROM purchase_mast ...` and you choose the columns you want to match up. You don't have to do it row by row, it can be done in one batch of rows. Have you read documentation? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I tried INSERT INTO score_mast
SELECT package_id, user_id
from purchase_mast. But it give error  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, you want to copy the `user_id` and `package_id` fields from the `purchase_mast` table to the `user_id` and `package_id` fields, respectively, of the `score_mast` table. If that is what you wanted to do, then you could do this

```
INSERT INTO score_mast(user_id, package_id) SELECT user_id, package_id FROM purchase_mast;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: No problem bro. Happy to help :)

Comment: plus one for simple query